# IP Filtering in Tomcat 6

Tags: security, servlets, tomcat6, servlet-filters

I know to filter using ip in tomcat 6,I have to use he bleow code
Valve className=”org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve” allow=”10.10.1[12]..*”/>

this works for me.But,How can I restrict access to a specific servlet.The above blocks for the entire application,I want to balock access for specifi servlet.I tried the below in web.xml,but its display tomcat error page 404

```
<filter>
      <filter-name>R</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve</filter-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>allow</param-name>
        <param-value>172\.16\.18\..*</param-value>
      </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>R</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>*/json</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can not use star(*) int the start of url pattern.